# Bootstrap new row when the current is filled

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, jsx

I am using React with Bootstrap and I render a list of cards like this:

```
render() {
    const stocks = this.props.stocks.map(stock => {
        return <StockListItem symbol={stock.symbol} name={stock.name}/>
    });

    return (
        <div className="card card-sec m-b-30">
            <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="mt-0 header-title">List of Stocks</h4>
                <ul className="list-inline widget-chart m-t-20 text-center">
                    <li>
                        <h4 className=""><b>500</b></h4>
                        <p className="text-muted m-b-0">Company</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4 className=""><b>505</b></h4>
                        <p className="text-muted m-b-0">Stock</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4 className=""><b>1</b></h4>
                        <p className="text-muted m-b-0">Portfolio</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-group">
                    {stocks}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The list item look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div class="card text-center" style={{width: '15rem'}}>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.symbol}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{this.props.name}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The question is, how can I render cards beside each other if it's enough space and if it's not, put the followings in new rows.
I know about the `row` class in Bootstrap, but the problem is that the items are rendered and I don't know where to put that class.

Comment: Please view the message on the bootstrapping tag and choose a more appropriate tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap whole component content with container that has `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```